# Connecting SQL DB in azure to Websites

Tags: azure

i have installed an SQL Server 2012 on an Azure VM,

and i want to access it from my "azure web sites",

the azure websites cannot be set to any affinity groups because they are in preview mode, yet i did created them on the same data-center as the VM... my VM has its private IP from our private network in azure and a public IP and public DNS

i want to access the Database from the "azure web sites" without having the traffic to cost me money.

what is the best way to do so ? 
Should i just use the public dns ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are wanting to use a traditional SQL installation versus using the Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Yes, i am migrating from another cloud and i wish to keep the use of my virtual machine as its is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct: You'll access your SQL Server virtual machine through its public dns name, and you'll need to set up database security accordingly. You can't set up a virtual network, since this isn't a supported feature of Websites, and you won't be able to rely on endpoint ACLs (introduced this week), since there's no assigned VIP for Websites.

The traffic won't cost you anything as long as the Websites deployment and Virtual Machine deployment are in the same data center.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just want to make sure the the azure routers will know to rout the traffic inside their network even if i would use the public ip/dns...

Comment: That's the way it works: If you have traffic between two services in the same data center, there's no charge, even if accessing via public ip address. Just think of all the services: SQL Database, Storage, Active Directory, Mobile Services, your own Virtual Machines, Web Sites, etc. Within a data center, no bandwidth charges. You can also look at the [data transfer FAQ](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/) which explicitly calls this out (referencing a data center as a *sub region*).